# Infinitive or gerund in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

Is the following sentence correct?

> Living in US for 10 months helped me to grow culturally, academically, professionally and personally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Living in the US for ten months helped me to grow culturally, academically, professionally, and personally."

Add "the" and it's fine.